# How to access to iframe element?

Tags: javascript, iframe

When you have a loop through all iframes in a page like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="a"><iframe src="..." /></li>
    <li id="b"><iframe src="..." /></li>
    <li id="c"><iframe src="..." /></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
    for (var i = 0;  i < window.frames.length;  i++) {
        if (window.frames[i].getName() == selector) {
            frame_item = ????
            break;
        }
    }
```

How can I get the DOM element for the < iframe>? Or following the example, how can I get the ID for the < li> item inside the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATED** answer.

window.frames references directly to the IFRAME context (iframe's window object). AFAIK you cannot obtain IFRAME object by this way. You can access IFRAME's variables via *window.frames[0].myVar*.

To get all IFRAME node/objects use:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); //all iframes on page
for(var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++){
    alert(iframes[i].parentNode.id); // LI.id
    alert(iframes[i].contentWindow.myVar); //iframe's context
}
```

Alternatively you can assign id to UL element and

```
var ul = document.getElementById('ul_id');
var iframes = ul.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); //all iframes in UL
...
```

Comment: window.frames[i].parentNode is undefined (Chrome)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. it references directly to the iframe's context. See updated answer.

Comment: Same problem as Alex Thomas answer: I have to call a javascript function on the child iframe. I cannot trust on the child DOM structure or the container.

Comment: You dont have to trust DOM structure. document.getElementsByTagName is DOM equivalent to window.frames. You will get DOM object (IFRAME) to work with or by cotnentWindow to call its functions. Another case is to get LIs ID if you dont knwo the structure, but you can still loop parents to find particular element.

Answer (score 1):

To get elements from within an iframe using jquery:

`$("iframe_id_or_class").contents().find(*element*)`

**Update**

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
      $("iframe", this).contents().find(*element*);
});
```

Comment: JQuery too? Good call my friend ;)

Comment: Ok, this is perfect, but that's not the question :) I need to access the frame context from within the loop.

Comment: That's ok if you know the DOM structure in the inner iframe, but I have only access to functions (standard API inside any iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I would STRONGLY suggest using the JQuery Javascript library for writing Javascript in general as it makes the whole thing easier, but ESPECIALLY for selectors as you can use CSS selectors.
So in this case you would use

```
var id = [];

$("ul li").each(function(){
      id.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

***EDIT***

Is this what you require?

```
$("iframe").each(
    function(){
         if($(this).attr("name")==desired_name)
             alert($(this).parent());
    }
);
```

Comment: I use Jquery, but I've simplified the problem here to javascript plain code :) The problem here aren't selectors, are to get the ID inside this loop.

Comment: this loop pushes the ID of each `li` into the `id` array