# List All Forms Elements in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**I want to make list of all the form elements** *(including the **FORMs inside** the **nested FRAME** or **IFRAME**)* within a **HTML document**.

The list would look like:

Forms For Page: (1)www.example.com

1. frmTestNameB
2. frmTestNameB

Forms For Page: (1)(1)www.example.com/IFramePage.htm

1. frmFormOfIFrame

Forms For Page: (1)(1)(1)www.example.com/Nested/NestedIFramePage.htm

1. frmFormOfNestedIFrameA
2. frmFormOfNestedIFrameB
3. frmFormOfNestedIFrameC

Forms For Page: (1)(2)www.example.com/IFramePage.htm

1. frmFormOfIFrame.htm

etc.

**CORRECT/MODIFIED JavaScript code** to perform this action is needed, please.

**I am exploring on this below code but it fails**:

```
var sFormNames = '';

function getFormsNamesForAnyDoc(objDoc) {
  var arrForms = objDoc.Forms;
  sFormNames += '\n\n List of Forms for WebPage' + objDoc.location.href + '\n';
  for (k = 0; k < objForm.length; k++) {
    sFormNames += objForm[k].name + '</td>\n';
  }
}

function getAllFormsName(objWindow) {
  getFormsNamesForAnyDoc(objWindow.document);
  if (objWindow.frames.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < objWindow.frames.length; i++) {
      getAllFormsName(objWindow.frames[i]);
    }
  }
}

//Calling
getAllFormsName(window);
console.log(sFormNames);
```

Comment: Can you please put something on fiddle..

Answer (score 2):

The following code was made available by  [Chris Pietschmann](http://pietschsoft.com/author/crpietschmann) in the article [JavaScript: Loop through all elements in a form](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2006/06/01/Javascript-Loop-through-all-elements-in-a-form)

```js
 function DisplayFormValues() {
   var str = '';
   var elem = document.getElementById('frmMain').elements;
   for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
     str += "<b>Type:</b>" + elem[i].type + "&nbsp&nbsp";
     str += "<b>Name:</b>" + elem[i].name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     str += "<b>Value:</b><i>" + elem[i].value + "</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     str += "<BR>";
   }
   document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = str;
 }
```

```html
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
  <input type="hidden" name="ElemHidden" value="some hidden text" />
  <input type="text" name="ElemText" value="some text" />
  <br />
  <textarea name="ElemTextArea">Some text area text</textarea>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="DisplayFormValues();" />
</form>
<hr />
<div id="lblValues"></div>
```

This code for the  and  elements is provided by [Jan Pfeifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891461/jan-pfeifer) in the post [How to access to iframe element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685905/how-to-access-to-iframe-element#)

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); //all iframes on page
for(var i=0; i<iframes.length; i++){
    alert(iframes[i].parentNode.id); // LI.id
    alert(iframes[i].contentWindow.myVar); //iframe's context
}
```

Comment: Try this and let me know ok

Comment: This code is **OK for a single page document**, but my case is to display the **FormElements for the main HTML Page as well as all the forms available inside nested _FRAMEs_ and nested _IFRAMEs_** of the main document.

Comment: You can add the frames too in the same code try it.. yourself...ok

Comment: if possible please generate the code (with proper error handling, i.e. cross domain issue for iframe/frame) for me for frames(frame and iframe) as well as for nested frames(frame and iframe), please :)

Comment: please can you give me some time... I will.ok

Comment: Now try it and let me know.... ok and you can replace the iframe with simple frame too.ok